# Select single first occurrence of row against distinct local ID from a table and insert it in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want a postgre SQL query that selects only first row from table against distinct LocalID and enter the result in another table. 
Records:

```
   ID| LocalID| Name
   1     233    Tim
   2     633    John
   3     633    Alex
   4     234    Mike
   5     233    Dave
   6     556    Kim
```

Wanted result:

```
   ID| LocalID| Name
   1     233    Tim
   2     633    John
   4     234    Mike
   6     556    Kim
```

I tried using

```
CREATE TABLE Weeklylist AS (select distinct on (localid) * from Monthlylist)
```

But this query select the last distinct record and enters it into the table. All i want is the first occurrence of the row containing distinct localID should be entered in the table.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Answer (score 2):

The use of `distinct on` in your existing statement indicates that you are using Postgres.

The problem with your query is that it is missing an `ORDER BY` clause. Without it, it is *undefined* which record will be selected (you are seeing the last record being picked, but this is not guaranteed to be consistent over subsequent executions of the same query). So, add the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
create table Weeklylist as 
select distinct on (localid) * from Monthlylist order by localid, id
```

Side note: parentheses around the `select` statement are superfluous here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DISTINCT ON` in `PostgreSQL` :

```
CREATE TABLE Weeklylist 
AS 
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (LocalID) * 
   FROM Monthlylist ml
   ORDER BY LocalID, ID -- Missing in your query
```

In `MySQL` older version correlated sub-query is one way :

```
SELECT ml.*
FROM Monthlylist ml 
WHERE ml.id = (SELECT MIN(ml1.id) FROM Monthlylist ml1 WHERE ml1.LocalID = ml.LocalID);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you need:

```
select *
from Monthlylist
where id in (
   select min(id)
   from Monthlylist
   group by localid
)
```

```
create table WeeklyList as
select *
from Monthlylist
where id in (
   select min(id)
   from Monthlylist
   group by localid
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=f335e18c17f3b9d3b9bf1f3a7a980e57)**

Answer (score 0):

You need a `subquery` and `join` to get your desired output.

```
create table Weeklylist AS (
    select t.* from Monthlylist t
      inner join (select distinct on (localid) * from Monthlylist) t1 on t1.localid = t.localid and t.id = t1.id
    order by id, localid)
```

see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9d1d17/1)